# NoReverseMatch(u"Reverse for 'rz' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments?

Tags: python, django

I Want to use url of an app(`rz`) using named urls and reverse.

My Views.py

```
return reverse('rz')
```

My Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = solid_i18n_patterns(

    url(r'^rz/$', rzV.as_view(), name="rz")  
)
```

The error I am getting

> NoReverseMatch(u"Reverse for 'rz' with arguments '()' 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rz/$']",)`

In db shell I checked

```
>>> reverse('rz')  
u'/None/rz/'
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your url doesn't take any arguments... what is it you're expecting it to do?

Comment: even if i remove kwargs from url still the same error is coming. I want to direct the control to the view attached to the url I am accessing by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls you need to set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` default.